# windows equivalent of wifi hotspot for lan

Tags: windows, dhcp, connection-sharing

Is it possible in windows to create the equivalent of a "wifi hotspot", but for LAN instead - i.e. have the computer (with mobile 4g card for internet) share its internet connection with a LAN device? if so, how would it be done? Preferably for windows 7, as windows 8 did their best to obscure this feature.

Comment: If this was possible; You would do this in Windows 8 **exactly** how you would do it in Windows 7.  Why can't you just use [ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: @Ramhound because I still need a DHCP server if I try to use ICS (that or to configure a second computer)

Comment: You asked how to share the 4G card's connection with the rest of your network, I assumed that meant, you already had a router ( or similar networking device ) to connect multiple devices to your host computer.  Your router can handle the task of being your DHCP server.

Comment: @Ramhound there isn't a router or anything, the 4G card is embedded inside the laptop and shows up as a separate interface - the windows computer becomes a DHCP server during "wifi hotspot" mode, and I would like to use that rather than a 3rd party DHCP program if possible

Comment: You want to take a wireless connection and turn it into a LAN connection. Unless you want to only have a single device connected to your host computer that would require additional hardware. **Besides ICS what you describe does not exist in Windows**  If the device also has a 802.11 device you might be able to combine the two connections and use something like [this](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, I am looking for a single device to be connected to it - and there is some sort of DHCP used in the wifi hotspot, I would just like that to be applied to a LAN port (which I don't see any technical reason why it couldn't be...)

Comment: I could be wrong, I am no expert when it comes to networking. What if you enable ICS "Internet Connection Sharing" on your mobile device and then bridge that with your LAN? It should in theory connect the two together? And as you said the computer with the shared 4G connection becomes the DHCP server, could it be as simple as connecting your other computer/switch via Ethernet cable through LAN? My two cents :/

Comment: @Malcolm it becomes a DHCP server but only on the wifi interface, not the LAN interface, which to me seems like an artificial limitation that could potentially be bypassed

Answer (score 1):

This enables hidden Win 7 hotspot / virtual adapter.

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Google for setup commands.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. A hostednetwork make a wireless an wireless access point. OP wants to share with a LAN connection. Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LAN network via Wifi or ethernet in Windows 7 using [Connectify Software](http://www.connectify.me/).

All you need is you must have wifi adapter in your desktop or laptop or LAN Port.

```
Install the Connectify software. Open the software and configure it. 
You can share Internet to your LAN Network using a Source like wifi, data card.
```

[image]

Comment: I am not trying to create a wifi network, I am trying to create a LAN network. And the SO policy tends to be more of an "answer here and have the link as a reference only" rather than a "go here to solve your problem".

Comment: @user2813274 I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: It seems like it could work, but I would still prefer a windows-only solution. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @user2813274 - This is a windows solution?

Comment: @Ramhound it's a (paid) 3rd party solution.. to something that windows has, but seems to have artificially crippled

Comment: There are open source projects that do exactly what this paid software does, but its not possible, without a third-party tool.